# How to automatically route to nested child using router.push in nuxt.js

Tags: nested, nuxt.js, router, children

I am using nuxt.js. Here is my file dir:

```
-- pages
      -- aaa.vue
      -- aaa (directory)
         -- bbb.vue
what i see in the generated file: router.js in .nuxt (directory):
routes: [{
    path: "/aaa",
    component: _5d6eb9d6,
    name: "aaa",
    children: [{
      path: "bbb",
      component: _15576d9f,
      name: "aaa-bbb"
    }]
  }],
```

here is what i want to do:

> from localhost:3000/aaa , I submit a form. It makes a call to rest
> service and then automatically goto "bbb" screen.

I tried to use **this.$router.push({ name: "aaa-bbb" })** but it still stays at **"aaa" screen**.

If I rename aaa.vue (ex: to 111.vue) Or "aaa" directory (ex: to "222"). Then I am able to route to "bbb" screen. But I dont prefer this way.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your `aaa.vue` of the root directory and rename it `index.vue` in the `aaa` directory.

Comment: Thanks. That is an option. But I am curious to see the solution when we don't rename any thing.

Answer (score 0):

I seems to me that this is not intended to be mixed. If you log the routes that nuxt creates, all pages from your directory will be attached as child objects to the route from your 'aaa.vue' file (attribute "children").

```js
// extract of console.log(routes)
{
 name: 'aaa',
 path: '/aaa',
 component: '/nuxt/pages/aaa.vue',
 chunkName: 'pages/aaa',
 children: [
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object]
 ]
}
```

If you put instead an index.vue inside your directory, nuxt creates an own entry for each file.

Probably the only way to achieve what you want is to extend the routes manually in the nuxt.config.js, see [extendRoutes](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#extendroutes) in nuxt docs.